# Different Ports for udp?

Tags: networking, udp, package, port

if i Receive upd packages via a FSM, Is It better to take different ports for each communication with other machines? F.e for avoid package lost? I know sockets are unique

Comment: No solution known?

Comment: I don't understand the question, maybe read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  e.g. I assume you mean "IP packets" (or datagrams) instead of "packages", but what are "upd" and "FSM"?  maybe you could read though some RFCs on other standard protocols and see what they do?